# Carpet under guitar amp or on floor

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers

I've seen a lot of carpets in studio and live sessions. Sometimes there are on the floor and sometimes directly under guitar amp. What's their purpose?

[image: carpet example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bare floors can cause extra reflection of sound, sometimes causing unwanted reverb or reinforcement of high frequencies. The carpets mute the reflective surface.

An amp sitting on a hard surface may produce some vibration between the feet and the surface, so a carpet can help with that. They also slide around more, so if you bump them they may skid, or in the case of tilt-back like the photo, fall over. Also, if the metal feet or corners have scratches in the metal, they can leave marks or scratches on unprotected wood floors.

Comment: They also reduce the sound of big clompy boots, if the guitarist forgot to wear soft trainers.